# Flink CEP unknown error alerted by IntelliJ IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I started studying Apache Flink's CEP libraries in Scala language, and as I was trying to create a PatternStream by executing `CEP.pattern(input,pattern)` as shown in the tutorial at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html, the IDE says that it "Cannot resolve overloaded method", referring to the `pattern` method. According to the implementation of `readTextFile` and `Pattern[String].begin('line').where(_.length == 10)`, both of which I used to create the input and pattern respectively, there shouldn't be any problems with the method's arguments or generic types.

Here goes the code I wrote. I know it isn't complete, but I couldn't complete it anyways since this problem came up.

```
package FlinkCEPClasses

import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer

class FlinkCEPPipeline {

  var props : Properties = new Properties()

  var env : StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
  env.setParallelism(1)

  var input : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/lines")

  var patt : Pattern[String,String] = Pattern.begin[String]("igual").where(_.length == 10)

  // Problem appears at the following line. A red subscript appears at the pattern method, 
  // saying the following: "Cannot resolve overloaded method"

  var CEPstream = CEP.pattern(input,patt)

  input.writeAsText("/home/luca/Desktop/flinkcepout",FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)

  env.execute()
```

Here goes my build.sbt file content:

````
name := "FlinkCEP"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-cep-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-cep-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % "1.9.0"

libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3" % Runtime

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.2" % Test```
````

My purpose with this code is just to see it running a simple "where" condition, it shouldn't have any greater utility besides that. I'm using IntelliJ as IDE. Also, I'm not sure if Scala's libraries for CEP are ready to be used. I would appreciate if anyone could shed any light over this.

Comment: Is that the IDE error or the compiler error? Does the code build at all?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It is both. I can't even build the project. It finds an error at the exact same line mentioned above. The error message is: "type mismatch; found :Pattern[String,String](in org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern); required: Pattern[?, _ ](in org.apache.flink.cep.pattern); var CEPstream = CEP.pattern(input,patt)", but I don't understand how I can fix this, I don't even see what possible error it is, since "?" represents any type, and although I'm not sure what "_" represents in this case, it should be something similar to a wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally solved the problem after looking at @DavidAnderson 's github examples. Since I made many changes, I can't say for sure if my solution will work for you, but i changed from `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream` to `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, DataStream, _}`. Watch out for ambiguous imports and make sure you're importing the real required classes.

I'm gonna list all my imports and my build.sbt file so that you have full access to my configuration.

#### Imports

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.PatternStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.{CEP, PatternStream}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, DataStream, _}
```

#### Build.sbt

```
name := "FlinkCEP"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-cep-scala
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-cep-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-cep
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-cep" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-cep-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-cep-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-runtime
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime" % "1.9.0" % Test


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.9.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % "1.9.0"

libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3" % Runtime

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.2" % Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.PatternStream

...

val CEPstream: PatternStream[String] = CEP.pattern[String](input, patt)
```

See [github](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_scala/cep/LongRidesSolution.scala) for a simple example that uses CEP with Scala.

Comment: Still not working. I get the following error message when I try to build the project: (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream[String],org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern[String, _],org.apache.flink.cep.EventComparator[String])org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream[String] and (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream[String], org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern[String, _])org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream[String]
 can’t be applied to (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream[String], org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern[String,String])

Comment: At least it seems the problem lies on the wildcard operator used as the second generic type of Pattern object. I'm trying to find some documentation about this